# Does spring have a validation framework module that can be used in any layer for validatons?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

For  instance, I am using JSF + custom framework developed in our company. Now I want to use  a third party validation framework that can be used as an plug-in and it should not create  any dependency what ever may be the technical stack.

So my question is does spring provide any framework of that sort or if it's available how can I use that?

I am expecting a validation framework something like, which is configurable through XML.

Answer (score 0):

Spring does have a validation framework, but if you want minimal dependencies, then I'd suggest that you go with a Bean validation provider. It's a new(ish) official validation standard, defined in JSR-303.

There are several implementations at the moment. I'd give [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) a look.

Comment: gary  thanks for the suggestion  but  i  am  expecting a  spring  validation  without using  springmvc.  Does  JSR-303 provides the
solution  what  i a m  looking  for.

Comment: Actually  we are using   JSF+JobossEsB  appication so  will  JSR 303 fit in all the  layesrs  of vaidation  like we use webservices and  also  we  send and  get  information from  GDS  adapter  in  our  application  so  can  i  validate the  request  and  response  using JSR 303

Comment: @mahesh: JSR-303 validators don't depend on Spring at all (though spring does provide a suitable validator). JSR-303 is integrated into JSF and can easily be used with JBoss apps. So, yes, it'll do what you want.

Comment: thank  u .  so  you mean to  say if  am using  JSF  then  i  can use JSR303 standard ? and  what  about spring validation  framework  can  i  use it with  out  spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. Hibernate Validator is an awful piece of software (at least the versions that were current about a year ago). [Spring Validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) is a nice piece of software, that goes together well with the BeanWrapper interface.

But it's true: Spring Hibernate resides inside the Spring Context jar, which is unnecessary overhead. Hopefully there will be a separate version sometime.

Comment: It's changed a lot in the last year, since becoming JSR-303 compliant. Version 4.0 onwards are worth a look.

It's worth mentioning that Spring Validation also works as a JSR-303 provider these days.

Both are fine (they're pretty similar from a user perspective these days), but Spring Validation comes with more dependencies. If you're already using Spring, that's fine.